# Jdk-10 en Eclipse Mars.2

Tags: eclipse

Al intentar instalar en eclipse el jdk10, me sale el famoso error "target is not a JDK root. System library was not found".
Googleando he encontrado algunos bugs que mas o menos venian a ser lo mismo pero para java9, el cual instalando un plugin de soporte en eclipse a través del marketplace, se solucionaba, pero para el mars.2 no veo nada...

Alguna idea?

PD: soy un programador novato, y este es mi primer mensaje en este foro, disculpas si algo está mal.

Answer (score 0):

voy a ir por partes; el jdk10 no se puede instalar en eclipse, el jdk10 se instala en tu sistema operativo.
Es cierto que se creo un patch para una versión de eclipse para corregir un bug asociado con jdk 9.
Eclipse 4.5 es la version llamada "Mars" esta fue publicada en el 2015 y podia correr con jdk 7 o jdk 8 https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation, los packages de Mars 2 fueron publicados en febrero del 2016 http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/Mars/2. En esas fechas todavía no existía Jdk 9 ni jdk 10 https://www.java.com/es/download/faq/release_dates.xml. El problema es que jdk 10 (marzo 2018) no es compatible con eclipse Mars (febrero 2016).
La solución seria instalar la versión mas nueva de eclipse que es compatible con jdk 10, o instalar jdk 7 o jdk 8 que son compatibles con eclipse Mars